# how can i use fork() in Python3.3

Tags: python, windows

how can i use fork() in Python3.3
**This is My code :

Input:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os

def Child_process():
    print("We are in Child_Process")
    print("My PID: %d"%os.getpid())
    print("Child_Process is exiting")

def Parent_process():
    print("-------Parent_process---------")
    wpid = os.fork()
    if wpid==0:
        print("wpid is 0 means We are in Child_process")
        print("Child :%d"%wpid)
        Child_process()
    else:
        print("Execute Parent_process")
        print("Parent_process %d"%wpid)
        Parent_process()

Parent_process()
```

Output:

```
C:\Python33\python.exe C:/Users/Iem-Prog/Desktop/Py/Fork

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:/Users/Iem-Prog/Desktop/Py/Fork", line 21, in <module>
-------Parent_process---------
    Parent_process()
  File "C:/Users/Iem-Prog/Desktop/Py/Fork", line 11, in Parent_process
    wpid = os.fork()

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'fork'
```

Comment: Which operating system do you use? This is not possible under windows for example.

Comment: Investigate the `subprocess` and `multiprocessing` modules.

Comment: A good thing that it didn't work, because it calls itself infinitely and becomes a fork bomb.

Answer (score 10):

[`os.fork`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.fork) is only available in Unix-like system. You cannot use that in Windows.

> `os.fork()`
>
> Fork a child process. Return 0 in the child and the child’s process id
>   in the parent. If an error occurs OSError is raised.
>
> Note that some platforms including FreeBSD <= 6.3, Cygwin and OS/2 EMX
>   have known issues when using fork() from a thread.
>
> **Availability: Unix.**

Answer (score 3):

Since `os.fork` isn't available on your target, consider instead using the [`subprocess` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) or even (batteries-not-included) [`envoy`](https://github.com/kennethreitz/envoy.).

These create a convenient abstraction around launching children.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the python's default [`multiprocessing` package](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html). It works with both Linux and Windows.

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Array

def split_work_receiver(import_type, process_no, i, shared_arr):
   creds= login()

    if creds is not None:
        process_submissions(browser, i, import_type, process_no, shared_arr)
    else:
        print("Failed login.")
    return

def split_work(base_path, i, connection_url, database_name):
    shared_arr = Array('i', range(0)) # Used to send data across processeses
    processes = [
        Process(target=split_work_receiver, args=("arg1", base_path, i, shared_arr)),
        Process(target=split_work_receiver, args=("arg1", base_path, i, shared_arr)),
        Process(target=split_work_receiver, args=("arg1", base_path, i, shared_arr))]

    #Run processes
    for p in processes:
        p.start()

    while True:
        sleep(600)

    #Exit the completed processes
    for p in processes:
        print('Closed process: '+ str(p))
        p.join()
```