# Python Multiprocessing within Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, multiprocessing, jupyter

I am new to the `multiprocessing` module in Python and work with Jupyter notebooks. I have tried the following code snippet from [PMOTW](https://pymotw.com/2/multiprocessing/basics.html):

```
import multiprocessing

def worker():
    """worker function"""
    print('Worker')
    return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    jobs = []
    for i in range(5):
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker)
        jobs.append(p)
        p.start()
```

When I run this as is, there is no output.

I have also tried creating a module called `worker.py` and then importing that to run the code:

```
import multiprocessing
from worker import worker

if __name__ == '__main__':
    jobs = []
    for i in range(5):
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker)
        jobs.append(p)
        p.start()
```

There is still no output in that case. In the console, I see the following error (repeated multiple times):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 106, in spawn_main
    exitcode = _main(fd)
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 116, in _main
    self = pickle.load(from_parent)
AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'worker' on <module '__main__' (built-in)>
```

However, I get the expected output when the code is saved as a Python script and exectued.

What can I do to run this code directly from the notebook without creating a separate script?

Comment: I can run your code using `Python 3.6.3` there seem to be nothing wrong with your code. When you put all your code in a script and run the example code, you should be able to see the output.

Comment: Yes, I was able to get an output as well. However, it only worked when I saved the entire code as a script and then ran the script. How can an output be obtained within the notebook?

Comment: I can also get the output using the notebook.

Comment: Can you please share how you did that? I am using Jupyter and got nothing at the output. I ran the snippet of code at the very top of my question. I get:

AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'worker' on <module '__main__' (built-in)>

Comment: I copied and pasted your code into my notebook cell and pushed `ctrl+enter`. Then i saw the output.

Comment: Do you really want to start multiple processes on your Jupyter server?  They may be hard to kill.

Comment: Looks like I don't understand this properly at all. I can create a `script.py` file with all of the code and run in Jupyter using `%run script.py`. This gives the output on the console (not the notebook) the first time it is run. If I re-run the cell  `%run script.py` a second time, it throws an error inside the notebook!!?

Comment: I see a related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29629103/simple-python-multiprocessing-function-doesnt-output-results)

Comment: If you would like to do parallel computing using Jupyter notebook, you might want to [take a look at this](https://ipyparallel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Answer (score 29):

I'm relatively new to parallel computing so I may be wrong with some technicalities. My understanding is this:

Jupyter notebooks don't work with `multiprocessing` because the module pickles (serialises) data to send to processes. 
`multiprocess` is a fork of `multiprocessing` that uses dill instead of pickle to serialise data which allows it to work from within Jupyter notebooks. The API is identical so the only thing you need to do is to change

```
import multiprocessing
```

to...

```
import multiprocess
```

You can install `multiprocess` very easily with a simple

```
pip install multiprocess
```

You will however find that your processes will still not print to the output, (although in Jupyter labs they will print out to the terminal the server out is running in). I stumbled upon this post trying to work around this and will edit this post when I find out how to.

Comment: Doesn't work for me (Python 3.10), I get `+[__NSCFConstantString initialize] may have been in progress in another thread when fork() was called.`

Answer (score 7):

I'm not an export either in `multiprocessing` or in `ipykernel`(which is used by jupyter notebook) but because there seems nobody gives an answer, I will tell you what I guessed. I hope somebody complements this later on.

I guess your jupyter notebook server is running on Windows host. In multiprocessing there are three different start methods. Let's focus on **spawn**, which is the default on windows, and **fork**, the default on Unix.

Here is a quick overview.

- **spawn**

  - **(cpython) interactive shell** - always raise an error
  - **run as a script** - okay only if you nested multiprocessing code in `if __name__ == '__main'__`
- **Fork**

  - always okay

For example,

```py
import multiprocessing

def worker():
    """worker function"""
    print('Worker')
    return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    multiprocessing.set_start_method('spawn')
    jobs = []
    for i in range(5):
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker)
        jobs.append(p)
        p.start()
```

This code works when it's saved and run as a script, but raises an error when entered in an python interactive shell. [Here](https://github.com/ipython/ipykernel/blob/master/ipykernel/kernelapp.py) is the implementation of ipython kernel, and my guess is that that it uses some kind of interactive shell and so doesn't go well with **spawn**(but please don't trust me).

For a side note, I will give you an general idea of how **spawn** and **fork** are different. Each subprocess is running a different python interpreter in multiprocessing. Particularly, with **spawn**, a child process starts a new interpreter and imports necessary module from scratch. It's hard to import code in interactive shell, so it may raise an error.

**fork** is different. With fork, a child process copies the main process including most of the running states of the python interpreter and then continues execution. This code will help you understand the concept.

```py
import os


main_pid = os.getpid()

os.fork()
print("Hello world(%d)" % os.getpid())  # print twice. Hello world(id1) Hello world(id2)

if os.getpid() == main_pid:
    print("Hello world(main process)")  # print once. Hello world(main process)
```

Comment: I tried this, first thing this is only for cygwin/unix => https://stackoverflow.com/a/19547482/1225413 ,second this is no longer valid https://stackoverflow.com/a/52476456/1225413 .. When I tried this code, I got attribute error, os has no attribute fork

Answer (score 4):

Much like you I encountered the attribute error. The problem seems to be related how jupyter handles multithreading. The fastest result I got was to follow the [Multi-processing example](https://jupyter-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/stable/performance/multiprocessing.html).

So the ThreadPool took care of my issue.

```py
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool as Pool

def worker():
    """worker function"""
    print('Worker\n')
    return


pool = Pool(4)
for result in pool.map(worker, range(5)):
    pass    # or print diagnostics
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Save the function to a separate Python file then import the function back in.  It should work fine that way.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me on MAC (cannot make it work on windows):

```
import multiprocessing as mp
mp_start_count = 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if mp_start_count == 0:
        mp.set_start_method('fork')
        mp_start_count += 1
```