# Parallel running multiple python scripts through Multiprocessing

Tags: python, parallel-processing, python-multiprocessing

I have multiple independent python scripts which I want to run parallelly. I am trying to achieve this through Multiprocessing library. I tried below code but its keep on running and there is no output.

```
import os
from multiprocessing import Pool

processes = ['1.py','2.py','3.py']

def run_processes (process):
    os.system('python {}'.format(process))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    pool = Pool (processes=3)
    pool.map(run_processes, processes)
```

Please advise where am I wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
```

like it says in the first paragraph of the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) on multiprocessing.

Comment: I tried using this If statement but no luck. Updated the code in the question.

Comment: Why did you make your list of processes into a **tuple** rather than the **list** in the documentation?

Comment: I tried with list as well; but still not working.

Comment: Ok, try changing it to `os.system(f'ls {process}')` If it lists your files, that means you need to put the full path to Python in your command which you can find by running `type python`. If it doesn't list your files, that means your program is not running in the directory you expect.

Comment: I tried this as well but same problem. Code is keep on running and not giving any output.

Comment: Ok, what is the **exact** command you use to run the script please? And can you add a line after `if __name__ ...` with `print(os.getcwd())`

Comment: Sorry Mark, what do you mean by _exact command you use to run the script_ ?

Comment: What did you type in your Terminal to run your script?

Comment: Currently I am using this Jupyter Notebook.. Is it not meant for Jupyter Notebook?

Comment: Mmm... maybe try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/54252710/2836621