# The function is already defined in a previous cell but error says it is not defined

Tags: function, pool, nameerror, multiprocess, metpy

I am using jupyter notebook. The following code uses some functions defined in the metpy package (dewpoint_from_relative_humidity) to define a new function "calc".

```
import numpy as np
import xarray as xr
from time import time
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
from metpy.units import units
from metpy.calc import cape_cin, dewpoint_from_relative_humidity, parcel_profile, most_unstable_cape_cin, mixed_layer_cape_cin
from metpy.calc import dewpoint_from_relative_humidity
from multiprocessing import Pool
from pytictoc import TicToc # conda install pytictoc -c ecf


data1  = xr.open_dataset(r'new.nc')
data = data1.sel(latitude = slice (50,45), longitude = slice(-110,-108))
data.r.values = data.r.values/100
data.t.values = data.t.values-273
data.t.attrs['units'] = 'degree_Celsius'
data.r.attrs['units'] = 'dimensionless'
data.level.attrs['units'] = 'hectopascal'

## reversing pressure levels descending
data = data.isel(level=slice(None, None, -1))
p = data.level

#Defining the calc function using the metpy functions: dewpointy_f_R_H and Most_unstabe_cape_cin
def calc(idata):
    p1 = idata[0] 
    t1 = idata[1]
    rh1 = idata[2]
    
    td1 = dewpoint_from_relative_humidity(t1,rh1)

    cape = most_unstable_cape_cin(p1, t1, td1)
    #print(cape)
    return cape

SP_emp = data.drop_vars(['t'])
SP_emp['cape'] = SP_emp['r']*0
SP_emp = SP_emp.drop_vars(['r'])

#Dropping 'level' dimension
SP_emp = SP_emp.mean(['level'])


from multiprocess import Pool
from pytictoc import TicToc

if __name__ ==  '__main__':
     pool = Pool(processes = 8)
    #num_processors = 4

mucape_res = np.zeros((data.t.time.size, data.t.latitude.size * data.t.longitude.size)) # time * lat * lon
print(mucape_res.shape)
    
for lat in data.latitude.values:
        for lon in data.longitude.values:
            for tim in data.time.values:
                t = TicToc()
                t.tic()
                Temp = data.t.sel(time =tim, latitude=lat, longitude = lon)
                #print(Temp)
                RH = data.r.sel(time =tim, latitude=lat, longitude = lon)
                #print(RH)
                #print(TD)
                sets = p,Temp,RH
                out = pool.map(calc,sets)
                #out = calc(set)
                cape_mag = out.magnitude
                SP_emp.cape.loc[dict(time = tim,longitude = lon, latitude = lat)] = cape_mag
                t.toc()
                #pool.close()
```

But when this defined function is used further in the loop it gives the following error:

```
NameError: name 'dewpoint_from_relative_humidity' is not defined
```

Why is the error coming if the function has already been defined previously in 'calc', is there any problem with the pool or the way a native function is defined inside a new function?

Comment: Does your comment "in a previous cell" mean that you are working in a jupyter notebook?  If so, does it work to put everything in a single cell, or to not use a notebook (i.e. just a text file)?  Each cell in a notebook is a different namespace, so it doesn't exactly correspond to the global namespace -- and thus when you are referencing other defined objects, you have to make sure that the objects are in the global dict.

Comment: I should've mentioned this, yes I am working in a jupyter notebook. Running the whole code in single cell also doesn't fix the issue. I will look more into the namespace related issues. Thank you for the direction.

Comment: It's probably the multiprocessing aspect. I think the easiest way to directly test is to add the import statements inside the function `calc()` as well and and see if that fixes what title issue. But you might have bigger fish to fry here as I've seen in several places that `multiprocessing.Pool` & Jupyter don't mix, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75824360/8508004). Should you be using `multiprocessing.ThreadPool`? See that reference, and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54252710/8508004), and [here](https://jupyter-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/stable/performance/multiprocessing.html).

Comment: A few more questions: Are you on windows? `Pool` on windows is different than on a MacOS or Linux. I see you are importing `Pool` from both `multiprocess` and `multiprocessing` -- they are different packages. The second is part of the standard library, while the first (I'm the author) is a serialization-enhanced fork of `multiprocessing`. Do you know which package's pools you are using? If you are using `multiprocess`, you can alter the interaction with the global namespace through `dill.settings['recurse']`. Another check to see if it's a namespace issue is to use `multiprocess.dummy.Pool`.

Comment: @MikeMcKerns You should post that as an answer, because I'm pretty sure that's the issue.

Comment: If serialization is the issue due to namespacing problems, then @Wayne has given a potentially straightforward workaround, which is to ensure the function `calc` is self-contained (i.e. include the imports and other dependencies inside the function definition, etc).